# Populate a GravityForms field with selected choice from dropdown menu with jQuery (not with the value of that choice)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm creating a form in GravityForms and I need to get the text from the selected dropdown option. I have a working jQuery script which works great. Only issue is that it gives me the value of the selected item instead of the text label.

```
 var selectHandler = {

    init: function() {
     
    var select = jQuery('#input_52_2')[0]; //field id to listen
    if(typeof select === 'undefined' || !select) {
        return;
    }
     
    //Value (before change)
    selectHandler.setEmail.apply( {value: select.value} );
     
    jQuery(select).on('change', this.setEmail);
},
 

setEmail: function(ev) {
     jQuery('#input_52_25')[0].value = this.value;
}
};
jQuery().ready( selectHandler.init() );
```

The result is the value of the selected dropdown item in the input_52_25 field, as expected. What I would like to get is the text from the selected item instead of the value. I've searched a lot and tried different solutions and am a bit stuck now.

Comment: this.textContent?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. This give's me the text, so one step closer but it gives me all the selection option from the dropdown, instead of only the selected one. Maybe you know a solution for that?

Comment: this.options[this.selectedIndex].text

Comment: Thanks again, i'm a bit lost now..sorry just starting to discover jQeury. Can you tell me where i put your suggestion in the code?

Comment: i solved it! jQuery("#input_52_2 option:selected").text();

Comment: or bit more complete...          jQuery('#input_52_25')[0].value = jQuery("#input_52_2 option:selected").text();